# How to count long and short winning and losing trades in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

In pine script, for a strategy I'd like to get the number of:

1. long winning trades
2. long losing trades
3. short winning trades
4. short losing trades

This information is available in Strategy tester's Performance Summary section, but what would be the code to get this in pine script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in variables.

```
strategy.wintrades: Number of profitable trades for the whole trading interval.
strategy.eventrades: Number of breakeven trades for the whole trading interval.
strategy.losstrades: Number of unprofitable trades for the whole trading interval.
```

Here is a complete example for you:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

sma = ta.sma(close, 50)
longCondition = ta.crossover(close, sma)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(close, sma)

pnl = 100000

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", profit=pnl, loss=pnl, comment_profit="TP", comment_loss="SL")

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", profit=pnl, loss=pnl, comment_profit="TP", comment_loss="SL")

var long_win = 0
var long_loss = 0
var short_win = 0
var short_loss = 0

is_pos_closed = (strategy.position_size[1] != 0 and strategy.position_size == 0) or ((strategy.position_size[1] * strategy.position_size) < 0)
was_long = strategy.position_size[1] > 0
was_short = strategy.position_size[1] < 0
is_win = strategy.wintrades > strategy.wintrades[1]
is_loss = strategy.losstrades > strategy.losstrades[1]

long_win := is_pos_closed and was_long and is_win ? long_win + 1 : long_win
long_loss := is_pos_closed and was_long and is_loss ? long_loss + 1 : long_loss

short_win := is_pos_closed and was_short and is_win ? short_win + 1 : short_win
short_loss := is_pos_closed and was_short and is_loss ? short_loss + 1 : short_loss

plot(sma)
plotchar(strategy.wintrades, "strategy.wintrades", "")
plotchar(strategy.losstrades, "strategy.losstrades", "")
plotchar(long_win, "long_win", "")
plotchar(long_loss, "long_loss", "")
plotchar(short_win, "short_win", "")
plotchar(short_loss, "short_loss", "")
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't resolve the issue. These variables don't discriminate between short and long trades and return all trades. I need separate numbers of long wintrades, short wintrades, long losstrades, short losstrates. Any idea?

Comment: You can use `strategy.position_size` to figure out the direction.

Comment: Added a copmlete example for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it, I'll report back.